# Android Studio Keeps Crashing When Opening "navigation.xml" File

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

My project involved a navigation component but every time I try to edit my navigation.xml file, Android Studio will be crashed and I have to reopen it to get a macOS crash report. I have no clue how this happens, any solution?

Android Studio 4.1
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6858069, built on September 23, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.15.6
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin

Comment: Upload your code -> xml and kotlin/Java files. Without source code and error messages it is difficult to debug error.